# Reschedule the scheduled task in spring scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I have a Runnable class which is scheduled to run at fixed rate (I am using spring scheduler):

```
taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, startTime.toDate(),
            PERIOD * 1000);
```

Can I reschedule the task or change the period dynamically after it has been scheduled?

Comment: @Selim (Cannot comment, yet) The problem with that solution is that even if you change your Trigger state, the change will apply only after the currently scheduled task runs and completes, which means that if you want to run the submitted task some other time instead of the immediately following scheduled time, you can't. (see `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable#run`<br/>
see `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler#schedule(java.lang.Runnable, org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger)` )

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the following `DynamicPeriodicTrigger` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/intermediate/dynamic-poller/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/poller/DynamicPeriodicTrigger.java

So you have to create a DynamicPeriodicTrigger instance (with fixedRate = true)  and put the reference into `taskScheduler.schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger);` method.

You can than dynamically change object attributes, to change execution periods on the fly.